# Where to define server/credentials when connecting to External Objects?

Tags: apex, administration, externalobjects

This must be really simple and I'm completely overlooking it but where are the credentials/server specified when defining an External Data Source?

In this org's case, we have a custom External Data Connection that is created in Apex to connect to a SQL Server. There are two classes, one for the External Data Provider and one for the External Data Connection, very similar to the ones that are in the SF documentation. They work great but we are looking at expanding this functionality and also connecting a sandbox to our test SQL server.

I'm just trying to connect a sandbox to a test version of this SQL Server but I'm unable to find where the server/login credentials are defined. I don't see them in the Apex code or on the External Data Source page. Is there somewhere that I would be able to see these details?

Authentication is set to Anonymous and the protocal is No Authentication, so I guess there are no credentials required but where would the server be defined/updated to a test environment?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=apex_add_external_data_source.htm&type=5